# Include chapters using foreach

Tags: include, automation, foreach

I have seperate .tex files in a directory named chapters in the main directory. 
I would like to include/input those. After some research a solution like the one below could be possible. Unfortunately I get "Undefined control sequence."

```
   \ForEach \i in {1,...,10}{
    \InputIfFileExists{chapters/\i.tex}
   }
```

Comment: `\ForEach` should be `\foreach`.

Comment: This appears to be the same question asked by a different user yesterday http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226897/can-latex-automatically-search-directories-and-include-discovered-files#comment534230_226897

Comment: In order to use `\foreach` (not `\ForEach`), you have to add `\usepackage{pgffor}`.

Comment: The syntax is `\InputIfFileExists{filename}{true branch}{false branch}`, as far as I know (amongst `\foreach`) of course

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some remarks:

- `\ForEach` might be defined by some package, but the syntax looks like `pgf`'s `\foreach`. TeX/LaTeX is case sensitive. At least package `pgffor` should then be loaded unless TikZ or `pgf` is used anyway.
- `\i` is a quite bad name for including text files, because `\i` might be used in some languages, it usually generates a "i" without dot: ı. The example therefore uses `\ChapterNumber`.
- `\InputIfFileExists` takes three arguments, the file name and two code arguments for the cases that the file exists and is missing.
- It seems, that chapter files are included, which should start and end at page boundaries. Then `\include` is the better choice. It internally uses `\InputIfFileExists`. Thus the compilation continues without error, if the chapter is not yet written. Then a reminder is printed on the console/log file, e.g.:

  ```
  No file chapters/7.tex.
  ```

  If the files are input via `\include`, then it is easy to compile only one chapter using `\includeonly`.

A full example can look like:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\foreach \ChapterNumber in {1, ..., 10} {
  \include{chapters/\ChapterNumber}
}
\end{document}
```

Macro `\foreach` puts the loop body into a group. This can be advantage, if local definitions should not leak out the chapters. Or a disadvantage, e.g. if the introduction chapter defines something that is supposed to be used in other chapters as well.

A loop without group and without additional packages:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}   

\makeatletter
\newcounter{FileNumber}
\@whilenum\value{FileNumber}<10 \do{%
  \stepcounter{FileNumber}
  \makeatother
  \include{chapters/\number\value{FileNumber}}%
}
\makeatother  

\end{document}
```

But I think, the structure of the document is much easier to understand, if the chapter file names contains real names instead of numbers:

```
\include{chapters/Introduction}
\include{chapters/History}
\include{chapters/Theory}
\include{chapters/Setup}
\include{chapters/Experiments}
\include{chapters/Results}
\include{chapters/Summary}
```

As compromise numbers can be added to show the correct chapter sorting order in a directory listing:

```
\include{chapters/01-Introduction}
...
\include{chapters/10-Summary}
```

Comment: Doing `\include` inside a group doesn't seem like a very good idea.

Comment: @egreg I have extended the answer. More elaborate solutions have the danger, that the simple task of including 10 files looks like a large program than a document. Writing, reading, maintaining, understanding such a program requires much, much more time than a simple plain list of `\include` statements (preferable with more speaking names).

Comment: An automized version (not with `\include`) could be invaluable if there's a long list of files to input (tables, for instance).

Comment: +1 for the named chapter files. `chapter01.tex` tells me nothing, and becomes meaningless if chapters are re-ordered.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `\foreach` after doing

```
\usepackage{pgffor}
```

(or `\usepackage{tikz}`). However there's a problem with `\foreach`: each cycle is performed in a group, so you'd be including the files in a group, which might have undesired consequences.

Also `\i` would be interpreted incorrectly if used in one of the files.

Solution:

```
\newtoks\listoffilestoinput
\foreach \i in {1,...,10}{%
   \edef\temp{%
     \the\listoffiles
     \noexpand\InputIfFileExists{chapters/\i.tex}{}{}%
   }%
   \global\listoffilestoinput=\expandafter{\temp}
}
\the\listoffilestoinput
```

Don't forget the trailing arguments to `\InputIfFileExists`

Of course you can use `\include` instead of `\InputIfFileExists`, if you so prefer:

```
\newtoks\listoffiles
\foreach \i in {1,...,10}{%
   \edef\temp{%
     \the\listoffilestoinput
     \noexpand\include{chapters/\i}%
   }%
   \global\listoffilestoinput=\expandafter{\temp}
}
\the\listoffilestoinput
```

Note that the extension should not be added with `\include` (it is optional with `\InputIfFileExists`, where `.tex` is implicit if no extension is present).

You might even abstract this in a macro to be defined in the preamble.

```
\newtoks\listoffilestoinput
\newcommand{\multiinclude}[3][\i]{%
   \global\listoffilestoinput={}% reinitialize
   \foreach #1 in {#2}{%
     \edef\temp{%
       \the\listoffilestoinput
       \noexpand\include{#3}%
       %\noexpand\InputIfFileExists{#3}{}{}% alternative version
     }%
   \the\listoffilestoinput
}
```

Then in the document you can use

```
\multiinclude{1,...,10}{chapters/\i}
```

or also

```
\multiinclude[\ChapterNumber]{1,...,10}{{chapters/\ChapterNumber}
```

The first mandatory argument is the list for `\foreach`, the second mandatory argument is the template. The optional argument (default `\i`) is the variable to use.

Note that with this approach (independently of the form you use), the variable `\i` is used just temporarily and has no side effects even if it is already defined (provided you don't use `\foreach` or `\include` as the variable name, of course); `\i` is perfectly good for this purpose.