# Find files in subdirectories to use with \input

Tags: external-files, filesystem-access

Is there a way to have TeX find all files ending on .tex in subdirectories of a certain directory to be used as `\input`?

In my document I would like to include a large number of files from a directory-tree which looks like this:

```
/transcripts/2013-05/2013-05-12/2013-05-12-transcript1/2013-05-12-transcript1.tex
                               /2013-05-12-transcript2/2013-05-12-transcript2.tex
                    /2013-05-14/2013-05-14-transcript1/2013-05-14-transcript1.tex
            /2013-06/2013-06-07/2013-06-07-transcript1/2013-06-07-transcript1.tex
```

I know I can define specific directories with

```
\makeatletter
\def\input@path{{./transcripts/}{./transcripts/2013-05}}
\makeatother
```

but it would be nice to be able to tell it something like

```
./transcripts/*/*/*/
```

Is there any way how to achieve this?

I know that [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226897/can-latex-automatically-search-directories-and-include-discovered-files) question addresses a similar issue.  However, I don't want to automatically include the files, they will still be specified by `\input{filename}:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document}

\input{2013-05-12-transcript1.tex}
...
\input{2013-05-12-transcript2.tex}

\end{document}
```

What I'd like to achieve is to be able to only type the name and not have to type the entire filepath every time.

**EDIT:** As per the suggestion below I have tried to edit  `/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf.cnf`  by adding `TEXINPUTS = /path/to/folder//:` so that it would search my folders recursively, but clearly I am missing some basic knowledge about how to do that.  Anyone able to help me with this?

**EDIT2 (2019):** 
I'm coming back to this question from a while ago:

(a) I haven't been able to get David's answer below to work. Any further help would be appreciated. 
(b) I would also still like to find a portable solution, to be specified in the preamble of the document itself. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've recreated your file structure and this works for me:

```
transcripts/
├── 2013-05
│   ├── 2013-05-12
│   │   ├── 2013-05-12-transcript1
│   │   │   └── 2013-05-12-transcript1.tex
│   │   └── 2013-05-12-transcript2
│   │       └── 2013-05-12-transcript2.tex
│   └── 2013-05-14
│       └── 2013-05-14-transcript1
│           └── 2013-05-14-transcript1.tex
└── 2013-06
    └── 2013-06-07
        └── 2013-06-07-transcript1
            └── 2013-06-07-transcript1.tex
```

The file `2013-05-12-transcript1.tex` is `\textbf{First}`, file `2013-05-12-transcript2.tex` is `\textbf{Second}`, file `2013-05-14-transcript1.tex` is `\textbf{Third}`, file `2013-05-14-transcript1.tex` is `\textbf{Fourth}`, and the example file is as follows:

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document}

\input{2013-05-12-transcript1.tex}
...
\input{2013-05-12-transcript2.tex}
...
\input{2013-05-14-transcript1.tex}
...
\input{2013-06-07-transcript1.tex}

\end{document}
```

**Windows**

I've saved it in `D:\transcripts`

***Temporary configuration***

Open a command line `cmd` (you do not need administrator privileges) and execute:

```
set TEXINPUTS=.;D:/transcripts//;
pdflatex sampleforum.tex
```

this will work until you close the command line, that is, you must execute this every time after close a command line ... tedious ... yes.

***Permanent configuration***

Open a command line `cmd` (you do not need administrator privileges) and execute:

```
setx TEXINPUTS .;D:/transcripts//;
```

close command line, open a new and execute:

```
reg query HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment
pdflatex sampleforum.tex
```

In this way we have configured `TEXINPUTS`in your environment variable and now it is permeating.

If you need to delete `TEXINPUTS` from environment variable, use:

```
reg delete HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment /v TEXINPUTS /f
```

Alternatively this can be done in a graphical mode adjusting your environment variable.

**Linux**

I've saved it in `~/transcripts`

***Temporary configuration***

in your command line execute:

```
export TEXINPUTS=.:~/transcripts//:
pdflatex sampleforum.tex
```

***Permanent configuration***

Add in your `.bashrc` the line:

```
export TEXINPUTS=.:~/transcripts//:
```

In both cases (Win/Linux) you do not need `admin` or `root` privileges, just a simple user account.

Another option would be to use `tlmgr conf auxtrees`, but the directory would have in `TDS` form.

Saludos

just in case someone else wants to replicate ... this line

```
mkdir -p transcripts/{2013-05/{2013-05-12/{2013-05-12-transcript1,2013-05-12-transcript2},2013-05-14/2013-05-14-transcript1},2013-06/2013-06-07/2013-06-07-transcript1}
```

it makes the job easier :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't bother with \input@path just set the `texmf.cnf` or environment variable `TEXINPUTS` to be

```
input/transcripts//:
```

the trailing `//` means to recursively search subdirectories and the `:` (or `;` on windows)  means just prepend this search path to the existing default, so all the standard places are still searched.

Comment: Would you mind expanding on how exactly to change `texmf.cnf`? I tried to add `TEXINPUTS = ~/path/to/input//:` to the users `texmf.cnf` in `/usr/local/texlive/2015/` but it still won't find the files.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I still couldn't get it to work.  Is changing `texmf.cnf` in `/usr/local/texlive/2015/` what you meant?

Comment: @jan if you set it in texmf.cnf you need to set the whole thing rather than just .//: as that is where it's set, in the file returned by `kpsewhich texmf.cnf`  or on the command line (with a shell such as bash) you can simply do `TEXINPUTS=.//: pdflatex yourfile.tex`   also `kpsexpand '$TEXINPUTS'` will show the currently active setting

Comment: Hmm, I still don't seem to get it. `kpsewhich texmf.cnf` gives me `/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf.cnf` as expected. Now I've added `TEXINPUTS = /path/to/folder//:` to that file. `kpsexpand '$TEXINPUTS'` gives me exactly that path. But when compiling it still doesn't find it.